# Jquery Uploader Call to undefined method UploadHandler::query()

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am trying to setup Jquery uploader, so that when it finishes the file upload it adds the file name to the mysql database.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases

In the uploadhandler.php I have added the following :

```
  $file->upload_to_db = $this->add_img($file->name);
```

AND also

```
///////////////////////////////////////
function add_img($whichimg)
{
$add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO u5b0y_chronoforms_data_submitusedequipment     (photo) VALUES ('".$whichimg."')") or die(mysql_error());
return $add_to_db;
 }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

As the documentation instructs........but when I go to upload a file, the file is uploaded correctly I get the following error in Firebug, but the database table isnt updated with the file name.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method UploadHandler::query() in
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have method  query() in your UploadHandler ? I think that no. In documentation I find next:

> So now you have to write a function for the SQL Query, copy & paste
>   the following code for example after the handle_file_upload function :

```
function query($query) {

         $database = $this->options['database'];
         $host = $this->options['host'];
         $username = $this->options['username'];
         $password = $this->options['password'];
         $link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

     if (!$link) {

         die(mysql_error());

         }

         $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);

    if (!$db_selected) {

         die(mysql_error());
         }

         $result = mysql_query($query);
         mysql_close($link);
         return $result;

}
```

Search this line - > **$this->options = array(**

Add the following Code in the next lines :

```
// mysql connection settings
 'database' => '**YOUR DATABASE**',
 'host' => '**localhost**',
 'username' => '**YOUR USERNAME**',
 'password' => '**YOUR PASSWORD**',
 // end
```

Did you made this?

Comment: Im using it inside Joomla so it already has a connection I think ?

Comment: Iv added it anyway, and still the same error, it uploads the file just fine, but then doesnt update the database

Comment: I do not work with Joomla, but I think you probably have a connect to the database. The point is that you need to make a query to the database and write you data to the table.How do you do that it is your right. You can add it using Joomla functions or like in plugin documentation. Did you write you data connection to the database in options array?

Comment: [**Accessing the database using JDatabase**](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)

Comment: I tried running it straight from the folder on the webserver, it uploads the photo, but still doesnt write the values to the database, and I have now added the above details you posted to the index.html file I added

Comment: I forgot to add, running it out of Joomla seems to give no errors, but also doesnt write anything either, even with the db connection info

Comment: My main problem is im not 100% sure if im sticking it at the end of the junction or after it, as because there is no gaps in the code it hard to tell where one starts and another finishes.

Comment: Hm, it is very strange, hard to help in the distance :-(